# Access Data type Yes/No field code in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

so basiclly im trying to do an accommodation system. So if i enter the unit ID and click on update btn, than it will display that room is occupied. which is a tick in database.
Below are my coding for that part

```
If txtunitid.Text <> "" Then

    cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE Accommodation SET Status = '1' WHERE Unit_ID = '" & txtunitid.Text & "';"

    cmdUpdate.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmdUpdate.Connection = cnnOLEDB
    cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox(txtunitid.Text & " " & "Record updated.")
    txtunitid.Text = ""
    addstudent.Show()
Else
    MsgBox("Enter the required values")

End If
cmdUpdate.Dispose()
```

i don't know which one represent yes no in vb.net. i did search and it says 1 and 0? and it gives me datatype criteria mismatched.

Comment: Start removing the single quotes around 1. Quotes means string and the database is expecting a boolean value. Thus the complain about datatype mismatch

Comment: SQL Server uses 1 and 0 in `bit` columns but, if I remember correctly, Access uses `True` and `False`.

Comment: i used true and false and it worked out just fine. But now i need to add another statement inside and it wont run.

cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE Accommodation SET Status = True , Student_ID = '" & txttp.Text & "' WHERE Unit_ID = " & txtunitid.Text & ";"

If i Delete the student ID it work just fine.. so i think the problem is in the student_id statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the boolean field to True or False:

```
cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE Accommodation SET Status = True WHERE Unit_ID = '" & txtunitid.Text & "';"
```

Comment: i used true and false and it worked out just fine. But now i need to add another statement inside and it wont run.



cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE Accommodation SET Status = True , Student_ID = '" & txttp.Text & "' WHERE Unit_ID = " & txtunitid.Text & ";"

If i Delete the student ID it work just fine.. so i think the problem is in the student_id statement.